# Add onclick event to options in select drop down dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down list created from an array in JavaScript. I want to do something with the selected value when I change the dropdown value.

```
var newArray = [3,5,4,6]

var container = document.getElementById('container')
var dropdown = creatSelectDropDown('thisDropdown', newArray)
container.appendChild(dropdown)

function creatSelectDropDown(id, array) {

    var dropdown = document.createElement("select");
    dropdown.id = id;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = array[i];
        option.value =  array[i];
        dropdown.options.add(option);
    }


    return dropdown;
}
```

So in the above code I would either have :

```
option.onclick = dosomething();
```

Or

```
dropdown.onchange = dosomething(getvalueofoptiontag);
```

I'm obviously missing something simple here ...

Fiddle to play with : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/hnLxt4xh/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can bind a function to change with this syntax:

```
dropdown.onchange = function(event) {
   console.log(event);
}
```

or using eventListener:

```
dropdown.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
   console.log(event);
}, false);
```

What you are doing wrong is that you have to pass a function to the onchange event, like:

```
var dosomething = function() { /* do something */}
dropdown.onchange = dosomething;
```

Comment: how to get the value from the selected option tag ?

Comment: Get the target of the event, then its value: event.target.value